# В базе данных ID всегда 0!

Tags: java, android, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Сделал базу SQL, но ID всегда 0.

Как исправить?

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," +
            KEY_DATE + " text," + KEY_HOUR + " text," + KEY_MINUTE + " text," + KEY_TODO + " text" + ")");
}
```

2.

```
if (id == R.id.btn_back1) {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
            int todoIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_TODO);
            do {
                Log.d("my_logs", "ID = " + cursor.getInt(idIndex) +
                        ", todo = " + cursor.getString(todoIndex));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d("my_logs","0 rows");
        cursor.close();

        Intent intent = new Intent(AddingActivity.this, CalendarActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.btn_add1) {
        cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_DATE, CalendarActivity.selectedDate);
        cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_HOUR, timePicker.getHour());
        cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());
        cv.put(DBHelper.KEY_TODO, name);

        database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, cv);

        Toast.makeText(AddingActivity.this, "TODO successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddingActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: А как вы заполняете таблицу данными, как выбираете их?

Comment: Я беру эти данные с одного поля ввода, а остальные поля автоматически(дата и время)

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, может быть там проблема, а не в создании таблицы

Comment: Добавил еще часть...

Comment: попробуйте autoincrement вообще убрать и ребилднуть проект, удалив его перед этим с девайса

Comment: Убрал - прога начала вылетать при нажатии на чтение из БД...

Comment: Колонка с ID имеет название `_id`?

Comment: Да.... Или так не правильно?

Comment: Колнка с автоинкрементом для хранения первичных ключей в андроид  должна называться именно `_id` (не `id`, `_ID` или там `Id`), все правильно

Answer (score 1):

А если автоикремент так написать?

```
AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Все-равно не работает!((

Comment: Похоже, что указывать автоинкремент для первичного ключа не нужно - он автоматически используется. Здесь посмотрите:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832401/sqlite-auto-increment-not-working

Comment: Это на самом деле не ответ